# JpaRepository read many times lines from postgres table

Tags: java, spring

I have a JpaRepository like this

```
public interface InfosRepository extends JpaRepository<Infos, String> {

}
```

and Infos class like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "infos")
@EntityListeners(Infos .class)
public class Infos {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private String age;

    public Infos() { }

    public Infos(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Infos(String name, String age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(String age) { this.age= age;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (this == other) ||  this.name.equals( ((Infos) other).name  );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}
```

So this class should list a postgres table called infos with column name and age. The process work except that I don't retrieve all values that I have in postgres and there are someone duplicate. For example I have in postgres infos table:

```
+-------+-----+
|   name|  age|
+-------+-----+
|charles|   20|
|charles|   32|
|charles|   55|
|    ted|   43|
| albert|   46|
|  clara|   23|
+-------+-----+
```

but in my Object Info I see:

```
+-------+-----+
|   name|  age|
+-------+-----+
|charles|   55|
|charles|   55|
|charles|   55|
|    ted|   43|
| albert|   46|
|  clara|   23|
+-------+-----+
```

I loose 20 and 30 since charles is in column id

I have this class to instantiate my object which listen postgres

```
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

   @Autowired
    private InfosRepository infosRepository ;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeConsumer() {
        InfosRepository infosRepositoryTest = infosRepository 
    }
}
```

when I  place a breakpoint at the line

```
InfosRepository infosRepositoryTest = infosRepository
```

in method initializeConsumer() I evaluate infosRepository which has the wrong element (lost and duplication)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you please share how are trying to find the records using the method of ApiKeyTopicRepository

Comment: thank you for the comment, I add to my post a piece of code where I initialize my object wich listen to postgre. I use annotation PostConstruct and Autowired. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ID is supposed to **uniquely** identify a row in the database. So, with this design, you're supposed to have only one "charles" in the table, and the name column is supposed to be the primary key.

If you want several charles, then you need to add a column containing a unique identifier, and map that column as the ID of the entity.

Note: `Infos` is a terrible name for such an entity. The name should describe what the entity represents. And it should be singular, since an instance of this class represents **one** row. A better name would be, for example, `Person`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there an annotation or a logic if I want only keep 2 column since I don't want to add id column in my postgre table. By the way, I use this name just for exemple.

Comment: No. JPA requires an ID. The only thing you can do is make both columns part of the ID, but an ID is immutable, so your entity will be effectively immutable. Do the right thing, and add an ID.